# Highcharts datetime label for column

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have been on this problem for hours now and can't figure it out.

My graph covers 1 day. There are 8 data points. Once every 3 hours. I want a column graph to display this data.

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1, 06, 01),
pointInterval: 3 * 3600 * 1000
```

I want the graph to start at 5am and display a data point every 3 hours.

Attached is a jfiddle. It looks good when pointStart is set to 6am. But if you change the starting point. The alignment gets messed up and the values don't change.

[Jfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/swollavg/2jLtzy6r/)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tickPositioner and return ticks in the particular places.

```
tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick =  Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1, 5, 0),
                increment = 3 * 3600 * 1000;

            for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2jLtzy6r/1/